# Nginx + magento 2 multisite setup with sub directory

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, magento2

I have Magneto 2 installed on the server and the main site is working with www.example.com and loading Magneto 2 root directory. Now have created sub-folder called "ksa" inside Magento root directory.

I need to load main site with "ksa"

For example

```
example.com/test.php to example.com/ksa/test.php
```

My nginx configuration

```
location ~ /ksa/ {
    rewrite ^/ksa/$ http://example.com/ permanent;
}
```

Comment: Change the root value to change the Magento folder. `location / {
    root /var/www/html/ksa;
}`